# Xamarin iOS 16.5: certificate is "Not in Keychain"

Tags: ios, xamarin

[image][image]I create a distribution cert in developer.apple.com, and I downloaded it, and double clicked it in the download folder on the mac. The cert appears in Keychain Access, but it does not seem to have a key associated with it.

In Visual Studio (Windows), 16.5, in tools > options > Apple Accounts, it says that the certicicate is "Not in Keychain".

Any help in how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi , does it occurs before 16.5 ? And you can share a screenshot to explain that .

Comment: @Junior Jiang -- It does _not_ occur before 16.5. I've included a screenshot from VS Apple Accounts unto tools > options > Xamarin. Both the distrib certs appear in Keychain Access on the Mac, but with no key associated. (The development cert, OTOH, which shows "Valid" here, has a key in Keychain Access.)

Comment: @Junior Jiang -- Also posted screenshot from Keychain Access on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

From shared screenshot , that's no problem about **Development Certificates** ,you will see the `private key` after clicking the down arrow .And it shows **Valid** in VS from PC(*THINKPAD2*).

However , the **Distribution Certificates** can not seet the down arrow . You should be sure that this Certificate is created from a new *CSR* file  Mac to generate the **Distribution Certificates** .You can not use other people generated *CSR* file or Development generated *CSR* file to generate a **Distribution Certificates** .

[image]

By the way , if certificates is in System Group , you can copy it to Login Group . Then it will show private keys .

[image]

Comment: I followed your advise and created a new distribution cert using a new CSR file. After downloding & installing on the mac, it showed up in Keychain Access with a private and public key pair. However, in VS in Windows, the new cert was still listed as "Not in Keychain".

Comment: So then what I did, I created another new distrib cert from Apple Accounts in VS, and it showed as "Valid". So I downloaded it on the Mac, and installedit and  It appeared in Keychain but without keys. I assigned it to my distribution profile, and then in VS in Windows in Apple Accounts I did "Download all profiles" and the I was able to see the cert and the profile in the choices in Bundle Signing in VS, and so all looks good. (Returning to Keychain Access, it now shows that it has a public & private key pair. Some lag before it shows?)

It all seems like smoke and mirrors.

Comment: Note that this new approach of creating the cert directly in VS, while it appears to have worked, and it generated a key pair, it did not involve the use of a CSR file. (At least not directly, perhaps behind the scenes it generated its own.)

Comment: @BobC Glad solved it . I forget to note that after downloading certificate to Mac , you need to copy Certificate from System Group to Login Group . Then it will show private key already . You can check that the all certificates in System Group not showing the private keys .https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtECB.png

Comment: @BobC Hi Bob, I hope you are well, could you post your comments as answer as they did help me to solve this problem. Thank you.