# ios Provisioning profile shows invalid

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have `xamarin.ios` app on app store and it was uploaded a 7 months ago.Now I am trying to create an update to existing app. The mac machine used for developing the app was changed now.I logged in the apple account in `xcode` and try to download the certificates using "`Manage certificate button`".It will download all certificates.

But I am getting an error in `xcode` says :

> Provisioning profile "XXXXX" doesn't include signing certificate
>   "Apple distribution: XXXXXXX"

I try to re download all certificates from `xcode`.But it didn't solved.

When I logged in my apple developer account under Profiles sections.It shows like this

[image: Profiles 1]

I saw in some articles says that we can revoke and extend the expiration. But when I try to edit,it shows like this.
[image: Profiles 2]

What Should I do exactly to resolve this issue? I need to update the existing app.Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: I believe you need to create a new Certificate for your new machine, then link the new certificate to your existing provisioning profile.  Or create a new provisioning profile for the new certificate.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the reply. How to  link the new certificate to your existing provisioning profile?

Comment: So deleting the inavlid profiles is okey?

Comment: you can edit a profile and select the certificates its linked to

Comment: I done as you said. I created a new profile and and assigned my certificates to it. I am using visual studio in windows and paired with mac. But visual studio now shows  "no-valid-ios-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain"

Comment: I installed the profile into mac also

Comment: @Anand Hi , have a check with this discussion , maybe helpful .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982834/xamarin-ios-16-5-certificate-is-not-in-keychain/61003908#61003908

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks bro

Comment: @Anand Hi , have you solved this ? If that discussion solve it , I will update that as asnwer :-）

Comment: Yes bro.Please update the answer

Comment: @Anand Thanks , I have update that in answer . Remember to mark that when you have time , thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Sure bro..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** , you need to check whether use the self-created **Distribution Certificates** in Mac .You can not use other people generated CSR file or Development generated *CSR file* to generate a **Distribution Certificates** .

[image]

**Second** , if certificates is in System Group , you can copy it to Login Group . Then it will show private keys . A private keys will show `valid` in Visual Studio .

[image]

Have a look at this discussion : [Xamarin iOS 16.5: certificate is "Not in Keychain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982834/xamarin-ios-16-5-certificate-is-not-in-keychain/61003908#61003908)