# Xamarin.Forms: iOS App doesnt show list with identities even though they are found under "iOS-Bundle-Signin"

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

this is my bundle signing

[image]

But when I wanna sign the archived version the list is empty:

[image]

Do the identites maybe have to be on the conntect mac or where are they supposed to be and why is the list empty? I cannot continue with the list being empty...

Comment: Hi , have a check with this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows . You need to use a distribution Profile to archive .

Comment: I have set up a distribution profile in the console. Now I can download that. If I click on that, nothing happens. It also doesnt show up in this list here. (It does however show up in the first picture)

Comment: Okey , have a try with follow steps to check :In Visual Studio ,  **Click Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Apple Accounts -> View Details** to see whether contain the provison file .

Comment: HEy, coul you send me a team viewer link maybe? I think that would be quicker and very awesome :)

Comment: It says there two provision profiles with the names i gave to them. but it says under certificates: not in keychain... ?

Comment: Sorry ,  can not supports a team viewer link here , you can submit this requirement in official supports of MicroSoft . Back to question, if shows `not in keychain` , you can have a look at [this dicsussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982834/xamarin-ios-16-5-certificate-is-not-in-keychain/61003908#61003908) , it will be helpful for you to solve this problem . And if works , let me know that :-)

Comment: Okay, I did everything. I downloaded all the profiles to the mac and put them into the key chain thing yet it still says "not in keychain"... :( can u email me team viewer? i am desperate!

Comment: Hi , hold on . Review the solution in that discussion in detail, follow that can solve your problem . In key chain , you need to move them from system group to login group .

Comment: Okay, but WHERE is the keychain? ON THE MAC? it is terrible

Comment: Yes , you also need to download the provision file in Mac , all file is used in Mac . Visual Studio here do the work with remoting to the Mac .

Comment: I did that and double clicked the file and it is inside this keychain. still it doest show up in my list.

Comment: Okey , if have did that , you will see the private key in Mac .Then re-connect to Mac in PC to check that .

Comment: It works. I had to manually export the p12 file from the mac and import it in vs on pc

Comment: Great ! Glad solved that :-)